# Tridion Template Builder throwing 401 error for Domain accounts

Tags: 2011, template-builder

We are getting below error when open Template builder when opened using LDAP(Domain) accounts.

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.Login(Boolean initData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Model.Login(Uri contentManager, NetworkCredential credentials)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.UI.CompoundTemplateDesigner.DesignerForm.LogonAs(Uri uri, Exception initialError)
```

When we use local Admin account to connect it is working and able to open Template builder.

Has anyone faced similar issue.

Update--- When I updated Tridion/Templating(/templating/compoundtemplatewebservice.asmx) authentication from Windows Authentication to Anonymous it worked. Is it recommended to keep anonymous for Tridion/templating.

Update 2-- When a new user is added from LDAP to Tridion the user is able to login. Existing LDAP users template builder is not opening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [online docs](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#docid=task_0826E529A8DE4C5DA8C0977CC70293DE&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=Appendix_LDAP_CMEWebSite.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_0826E529A8DE4C5DA8C0977CC70293DE&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=ldap&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1395059604099&currentQuery=ldap&currentScope=) [login required] indicate that the Content Manager Explorer website should be set to allow anonymous access if you wish to use LDAP authentication. Note that it is not recommended to use both Active Directory and LDAP authentication on a single CMS server

Comment: Tridion is set up with Anonymous authentication. Only Tridon\Templating is set to use Windows Authentication. It was working previously and failed after a License upgrade.

Comment: I would say that Tridion\Templating should also be anonymous to allow the LDAP authentication to correctly function

Comment: Do we have any reference on the same from Tridion Documentation .

Comment: I have updated question with new information.

Comment: Can the new users log into the Tridion Content Explorer GUI?

Comment: Yes the user is able to login to Tridion GUI.

Comment: Thats a bit weird - if they can log into the GUI, they should be able to log into the Template builder. Given that you had to enable Anonymous access, it sounds like the LDAP setup was not done correctly, so I would go through the docs and double check everything

Comment: We are asked to change to anonymous setting and it is working. Funny part is that how come it had been working so long with Windows authentication